# Calculate the total cost of the products within the shopping cart and displaying it at the bottom rather than manual input

Tags: javascript, html, css, visual-studio, function

I have made a checkout form that displays the cost of a product, the subtotal, GST cost, delivery cost, and total price. What id like to do is take the cost of each product which has the class `class = "price"` (but id assume that they may need an id), and add them together to get the total. This total would be calculated with an increase of 15% from the value of the subtotal plus the cost of delivery.

Here is the checkout form (sorry for the length) ~ there is some styling that isn't relevant as it is has been pulled from a page on the website.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated. My guess is that they need an id, then I would use getElementById to get the value and add them together, but I don't know how I would do this.

```html
<head>
  <link href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css'>
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/a076d05399.js"></script>
</head>
<main>
  <div class='payment-form'>
    <div class='checkout-tabs'>
      <div class='details-field'>
        <div class='details-inputs'>
          <h3>Accepted Payment Methods</h3>
          <div class="icon-container">
            <i class="fab fa-cc-visa"></i>
            <i class="fab fa-cc-mastercard"></i>
            <i class="fab fa-cc-apple-pay"></i>
            <i class="fab fa-cc-amazon-pay"></i>
            <i class="fab fa-cc-paypal"></i>
          </div>

          <label><i class="fa fa-user"></i> Full Name</label><input class='input-field ' type="text" placeholder="Bobby K Mack">
          <label><i class="fa fa-phone-alt"></i> Phone Number</label><input class='input-field ' type="text" placeholder="(###) ###-####">
          <label><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i> Email</label><input class='input-field ' type="text" placeholder="john@example.com">
          <label><i class="fa fa-institution"></i> City</label><input class='input-field ' type="text" placeholder="Mount Cook">
          <table class="half-input-table">
            <tr>
              <td>
                <label for="Country"><i class="fa fa-globe"></i> Country</label><input class='input-field ' type="text" id="Country" name="Country" placeholder="NZL">
              </td>
              <td>
                <label for="zip"><i class="fas fa-map-marker-alt"></i> Zip Code</label><input class='input-field ' type="text" id="zip" name="zip" placeholder="7999">
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
          <label for="input-field">Name on Card</label><input class='input-field ' placeholder="Bobby K Mack"></input>

          <label for="input-field">Card Number</label><input class='input-field ' placeholder="####-####-####"></input>
          <table class='half-input-table '>
            <tr>
              <td> <label for="input-field">Exp Year</label><input class='input-field ' placeholder="2021"></input>
              </td>
              <td> <label for="input-field">CVV</label><input class='input-field ' placeholder="123"></input>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </div>

      </div>
      <div class='order-info'>
        <div class='order-info-content'>
          <h2>Cart <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i></h2>
          <div class='devider'></div>
          <table class='order-table' id="checkout-itm-1">

            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td><img src='https://aoc-pim.s3.amazonaws.com/USA%20content/g2/CQ27G2/CQ27G2_F.png' width="100%"></img>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <br>
                  <span class='product-name'>AOC C27G2</span>
                  <button class="item-btn" onclick="removeItem1()">X</button>
                  <br>27" Full HD Curved Monitor<br>
                  <li class='product description'>Resolution: 1920x1080</li>
                  <li class='product description'>Refresh Rate: 165hz</li>
                  <li class='product description'>Response Time: 1 ms</li>

                </td>

              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>
                  <div class='price'>$429.00 (GST Inc)</div>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>

          </table>
          <div class='devider' id="dev1"></div>
          <table class='order-table' id="checkout-itm-2">
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td><img src='https://www.computerlounge.co.nz/data/media/images/catalogue/Products2/Peripherals/Mice/Logitech/22752_1.jpg?maxheight=950&maxwidth=600&quality=100&404=default.jpg' width="100%"></img>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <br> <span class='product-name'>Logitech G402 Hyperion Fury</span>
                  <button class="item-btn" onclick="removeItem2()">X</button>
                  <br>Gaming Mouse<br>
                  <li class='product description'>Movement Detection: Optical</li>
                  <li class='product description'>Programmable Buttons: 8</li>
                  <li class='product description'>Hand Orientation: Right Hand</li>
                  <li class='product description'>Maximum DPI: 4,000</li>

                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>
                  <div class='price'>$94.89 (GST Inc)</div>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
          <div class='devider' id="dev2"></div>
          <table class='order-table' id="checkout-itm-3">
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td><img src='https://www.pbtech.co.nz/imgprod/H/S/HSTLOG4443629__1.jpg?h=1434805038' width="90%"></img>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <br> <span class='product-name'>Logitech G332</span>
                  <button class="item-btn" onclick="removeItem3()">X</button>
                  <br>Stereo Gaming Headset<br>
                  <li class='product description'>Sound Mode: Stereo</li>
                  <li class='product description'>Microphone: Yes</li>
                  <li class='product description'>Interface: 3.5mm</li>
                  <li class='product description'>Colour: Black</li>

                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>
                  <div class='price'>$133.00 (GST Inc)</div>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>

          <div class='devider' id="dev3"></div>
          <table class='order-table' id="checkout-itm-4">
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td>
                  <img src='data:image/jpeg;base64,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'
                    width="80%"></img>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <br> <span class='product '>GGPC Legend</span>
                  <button class="item-btn" onclick="removeItem4()">X</button>
                  <br>RTX 2070 SUPER Gaming PC<br>
                  <li class='product description'>CPU: AMD Ryzen 7</li>
                  <li class='product description'>GPU: Nvidia RTX 2070 Super</li>
                  <li class='product description'>Memory: 16GB</li>

                </td>

              </tr>
              <tr>

                <td>
                  <div class='price'>$2,413.85 (GST Inc)</div>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>

          <div class='devider '></div>

          <div class="cost-sum-headers">

            <span style='float:left; '>
                                    <div class='total-font'>
                                    Subtotal
                                    </div>
                                    <div class='total-font '>
                                    GST
                                    </div>
                                        <div class='total-font '>
                                            Delivery
                                        </div>
                                    TOTAL
                                </span>
            <span class="cost_sum">
                                <div class='total-font '>$2,753.35</div>
                                <div class='total-font '>$398.16</div>
                                <div class='total-font '>$26.97</div>
                                 <div class="total-font">$3,172.11</div>
                                 </span>
            <button class='checkout-button'>Checkout</button>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>

</main>

<style>
  body {
    background-color: #424242;
  }
  
  .icon-container {
    text-align: center;
  }
  
  .fa,
  .fab {
    font-size: 3.125em;
  }
  
  .fa-heart {
    color: #ddd !important;
  }
  
  .fa-cc-apple-pay {
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg, rgb(119, 119, 119), rgb(255, 255, 255));
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  }
  
  .fa-cc-mastercard {
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(0deg, #ffef00, #ff6f00, #ff0000);
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  }
  
  .fa-cc-visa {
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(90deg, rgb(255, 255, 0), rgb(255, 255, 255), rgb(35, 38, 250));
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  }
  
  .fa-cc-paypal {
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg, rgb(0, 4, 255), rgb(0, 225, 255));
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  }
  
  .fa-cc-amazon-pay {
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg, rgb(255, 138, 4), rgb(255, 174, 0));
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  }
  
  .fa-google-pay {
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(0deg, rgb(255, 0, 0), rgb(241, 147, 40), rgb(5, 206, 22), rgb(0, 174, 255));
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  }
  
  .order-info-content .fa-shopping-cart {
    color: #212121;
  }
  /* Main body of checkout section */
  
  .checkout-tabs {
    height: 59em;
    width: 75.000em;
    background: #fff;
    display: flex;
    border-radius: 2.063em;
  }
  
  @media only screen and (max-width: 700px) {
    .checkout-tabs {
      height: 62em;
    }
  }
  /* 
     ========================================================================================================                                                   
                                             Payment Form                                                              
     ========================================================================================================
      */
  
  .payment-form h2 {
    margin-bottom: 0em;
    margin-top: 1.563em;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: 200;
    font-size: 1.2em;
  }
  
  .order-info-content h2 {
    margin-bottom: 0em;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    color: #212121;
  }
  
  .payment-form label {
    margin-bottom: 0.625em;
    display: block;
    color: #ddd;
  }
  
  .payment-form {
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    display: flex;
  }
  
  .order-table .product-name {
    font-weight: 500;
  }
  
  .order-table .description {
    font-weight: 200;
    font-size: 0.750em;
    font-size: .8em;
    list-style-type: none;
  }
  
  .half-input-table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
  }
  
  .half-input-table td:first-of-type {
    border-right: 0.625em solid #212121;
    width: 50%;
  }
  
  .order-info {
    height: 100%;
    width: 50%;
    padding-left: 1.563em;
    padding-right: 1.563em;
    position: relative;
  }
  
  .price {
    bottom: 0em;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0em;
    color: #21212180;
  }
  
  .order-table td:first-of-type {
    width: 25%;
  }
  
  .order-table {
    position: relative;
  }
  
  .devider {
    height: 0.063em;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 0.625em;
    margin-bottom: 0.625em;
    background: #21212185;
  }
  
  .cost_sum {
    float: right;
    text-align: right;
  }
  
  .total-field {
    width: 50%;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
  }
  
  .quantity {
    width: 10%;
    margin-left: 5px;
    float: right;
  }
  
  .price-right {
    float: right;
  }
  
  .checkout-button {
    border: solid;
    border-color: rgba(221, 221, 221, 0.281);
    background: rgb(53, 53, 53);
    padding: 0.7em;
    border-radius: 1.250em;
    font-size: 1.250em;
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 100%;
  }
  
  .checkout-button:hover {
    opacity: 95%;
  }
  
  .total-font {
    line-height: 1.2em;
    font-size: 1.000em;
    font-size: 1em;
    font-weight: 400;
  }
  
  .input-field {
    background: #ddd;
    margin-bottom: 0.625em;
    margin-top: 0.188em;
    line-height: 1.5em;
    font-size: 1.250em;
    font-size: 1.3em;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 0.313em;
    padding: 0.313em 0.625em 0.313em 0.625em;
    color: #fff;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
  }
  
  .details-field {
    background: #212121;
    height: 100%;
    width: 50%;
    color: #eee;
    justify-content: center;
    font-size: 0.875em;
    font-size: .9em;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding-left: 1.563em;
    padding-right: 1.563em;
    border-radius: 1.875em;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: white;
  }
  
  .details-inputs {
    margin-top: 1.563em;
    -webkit-flex-flow: column;
    -ms-flex-flow: column;
    flex-flow: column;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
  }
  
  .details-inputs h3 {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0em;
    margin-top: 0em;
    font-size: large;
  }
  
  .item-btn {
    color: red;
    background-color: transparent;
    border-style: none;
    float: right;
  }
  
  .item-btn:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  
  .checkout-form-1 {
    height: 300px;
    width: 400px;
    margin: 20px auto;
    border: 2px solid black;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: white;
  }
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

You do NOT need an ID since IDs need to be unique.

I do not have your delivery on the page so here is the total

Note: You HTML is quite invalid. You cannot have divs in spans. Also I would have the style sheet external and placed in the beginning of the head

```js
const prices = [...document.querySelectorAll(".order-info .price")]
  .map(price => +price.textContent.replace(/[^\d|.]/g, "")) // get rid of text and $

const sum = prices.length > 0 ? prices.reduce((a, b) => a + b) : 0; // sum the array of prices - if none, then 0
console.log(sum.toFixed(2)); // sum of prices

const costs = [...document.querySelectorAll(".cost_sum div")];
const total = costs.length > 0 ? costs.reduce((acc, cost) => {
  acc += +cost.textContent.replace(/[^\d|.]/g, "");
  return acc;
}, 0) : 0;
console.log(total.toFixed(2))
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #424242;
}

.icon-container {
  text-align: center;
}

.fa,
.fab {
  font-size: 3.125em;
}

.fa-heart {
  color: #ddd !important;
}

.fa-cc-apple-pay {
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg, rgb(119, 119, 119), rgb(255, 255, 255));
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}

.fa-cc-mastercard {
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(0deg, #ffef00, #ff6f00, #ff0000);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}

.fa-cc-visa {
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(90deg, rgb(255, 255, 0), rgb(255, 255, 255), rgb(35, 38, 250));
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}

.fa-cc-paypal {
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg, rgb(0, 4, 255), rgb(0, 225, 255));
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}

.fa-cc-amazon-pay {
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg, rgb(255, 138, 4), rgb(255, 174, 0));
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}

.fa-google-pay {
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(0deg, rgb(255, 0, 0), rgb(241, 147, 40), rgb(5, 206, 22), rgb(0, 174, 255));
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}

.order-info-content .fa-shopping-cart {
  color: #212121;
}


/* Main body of checkout section */

.checkout-tabs {
  height: 59em;
  width: 75.000em;
  background: #fff;
  display: flex;
  border-radius: 2.063em;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 700px) {
  .checkout-tabs {
    height: 62em;
  }
}


/* 
     ========================================================================================================                                                   
                                             Payment Form                                                              
     ========================================================================================================
      */

.payment-form h2 {
  margin-bottom: 0em;
  margin-top: 1.563em;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 200;
  font-size: 1.2em;
}

.order-info-content h2 {
  margin-bottom: 0em;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  color: #212121;
}

.payment-form label {
  margin-bottom: 0.625em;
  display: block;
  color: #ddd;
}

.payment-form {
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
}

.order-table .product-name {
  font-weight: 500;
}

.order-table .description {
  font-weight: 200;
  font-size: 0.750em;
  font-size: .8em;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.half-input-table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

.half-input-table td:first-of-type {
  border-right: 0.625em solid #212121;
  width: 50%;
}

.order-info {
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  padding-left: 1.563em;
  padding-right: 1.563em;
  position: relative;
}

.price {
  bottom: 0em;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0em;
  color: #21212180;
}

.order-table td:first-of-type {
  width: 25%;
}

.order-table {
  position: relative;
}

.devider {
  height: 0.063em;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 0.625em;
  margin-bottom: 0.625em;
  background: #21212185;
}

.cost_sum {
  float: right;
  text-align: right;
}

.total-field {
  width: 50%;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.quantity {
  width: 10%;
  margin-left: 5px;
  float: right;
}

.price-right {
  float: right;
}

.checkout-button {
  border: solid;
  border-color: rgba(221, 221, 221, 0.281);
  background: rgb(53, 53, 53);
  padding: 0.7em;
  border-radius: 1.250em;
  font-size: 1.250em;
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 100%;
}

.checkout-button:hover {
  opacity: 95%;
}

.total-font {
  line-height: 1.2em;
  font-size: 1.000em;
  font-size: 1em;
  font-weight: 400;
}

.input-field {
  background: #ddd;
  margin-bottom: 0.625em;
  margin-top: 0.188em;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  font-size: 1.250em;
  font-size: 1.3em;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 0.313em;
  padding: 0.313em 0.625em 0.313em 0.625em;
  color: #fff;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.details-field {
  background: #212121;
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  color: #eee;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: 0.875em;
  font-size: .9em;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding-left: 1.563em;
  padding-right: 1.563em;
  border-radius: 1.875em;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: white;
}

.details-inputs {
  margin-top: 1.563em;
  -webkit-flex-flow: column;
  -ms-flex-flow: column;
  flex-flow: column;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}

.details-inputs h3 {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0em;
  margin-top: 0em;
  font-size: large;
}

.item-btn {
  color: red;
  background-color: transparent;
  border-style: none;
  float: right;
}

.item-btn:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.checkout-form-1 {
  height: 300px;
  width: 400px;
  margin: 20px auto;
  border: 2px solid black;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <link href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css'>
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/a076d05399.js"></script>
</head>
<main>
  <div class='payment-form'>
    <div class='checkout-tabs'>

      <div class='order-info'>
        <div class='order-info-content'>
          <h2>Cart <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i></h2>
          <div class='devider'></div>
          <table class='order-table' id="checkout-itm-1">

            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td><img src='https://aoc-pim.s3.amazonaws.com/USA%20content/g2/CQ27G2/CQ27G2_F.png' width="100%">
                </td>
                <td>
                  <br>
                  <span class='product-name'>AOC C27G2</span>
                  <button class="item-btn" onclick="removeItem1()">X</button>
                  <br>27" Full HD Curved Monitor<br>
                  <li class='product description'>Resolution: 1920x1080</li>
                  <li class='product description'>Refresh Rate: 165hz</li>
                  <li class='product description'>Response Time: 1 ms</li>

                </td>

              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>
                  <div class='price'>$429.00 (GST Inc)</div>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>

          </table>
          <div class='devider' id="dev1"></div>
          <table class='order-table' id="checkout-itm-2">
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td><img src='https://www.computerlounge.co.nz/data/media/images/catalogue/Products2/Peripherals/Mice/Logitech/22752_1.jpg?maxheight=950&maxwidth=600&quality=100&404=default.jpg' width="100%">
                </td>
                <td>
                  <br> <span class='product-name'>Logitech G402 Hyperion Fury</span>
                  <button class="item-btn" onclick="removeItem2()">X</button>
                  <br>Gaming Mouse<br>
                  <li class='product description'>Movement Detection: Optical</li>
                  <li class='product description'>Programmable Buttons: 8</li>
                  <li class='product description'>Hand Orientation: Right Hand</li>
                  <li class='product description'>Maximum DPI: 4,000</li>

                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>
                  <div class='price'>$94.89 (GST Inc)</div>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
          <div class='devider' id="dev2"></div>
          <table class='order-table' id="checkout-itm-3">
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td><img src='https://www.pbtech.co.nz/imgprod/H/S/HSTLOG4443629__1.jpg?h=1434805038' width="90%">
                </td>
                <td>
                  <br> <span class='product-name'>Logitech G332</span>
                  <button class="item-btn" onclick="removeItem3()">X</button>
                  <br>Stereo Gaming Headset<br>
                  <li class='product description'>Sound Mode: Stereo</li>
                  <li class='product description'>Microphone: Yes</li>
                  <li class='product description'>Interface: 3.5mm</li>
                  <li class='product description'>Colour: Black</li>

                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>
                  <div class='price'>$133.00 (GST Inc)</div>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>

          <div class='devider' id="dev3"></div>
          <table class='order-table' id="checkout-itm-4">
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td>
                  <img src='https://www.pbtech.co.nz/imgprod/W/K/WKSGGPC50042__10.jpg' width="80%">
                </td>
                <td>
                  <br> <span class='product '>GGPC Legend</span>
                  <button class="item-btn" onclick="removeItem4()">X</button>
                  <br>RTX 2070 SUPER Gaming PC<br>
                  <li class='product description'>CPU: AMD Ryzen 7</li>
                  <li class='product description'>GPU: Nvidia RTX 2070 Super</li>
                  <li class='product description'>Memory: 16GB</li>

                </td>

              </tr>
              <tr>

                <td>
                  <div class='price'>$2,413.85 (GST Inc)</div>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>

          <div class='devider '></div>

          <div class="cost-sum-headers">

            <div style='float:left; '>
              <div class='total-font'>Subtotal</div>
              <div class='total-font '>GST</div>
              <div class='total-font '>Delivery</div>
              TOTAL
            </div>
            <div class="cost_sum">
              <div class='total-font '>$2,753.35</div>
              <div class='total-font '>$398.16</div>
              <div class='total-font '>$26.97</div>
              <div class="total-font">$3,172.11</div>
            </div>
            <button class='checkout-button'>Checkout</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</main>
```

Comment: It is returning an error that says "reduce of empty array with no initial value." Did it actually work where it inputted the value into the total cost or does this code just calculate the total?

Comment: This only reads existing prices from elements with class=price - you need to give more details if you want to enter stuff

Comment: sorry, that is my bad expaining. What i was wanting to do was pull the data from the costs then calculate the total and update the total cost element

Comment: This still doesnt change that it is throwing an error

Comment: I have updated the code. I sum and calculate total. If you want this to happen on check of a checkbox for example, you need to show alternative code

Answer (score 1):

you can use [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)

for example:

```
// Get all the elements that have the `.price` class
const prices = document.querySelectorAll(".price");
```

Then you could loop over prices use `array.reduce()`

```
// convert the nodeList into an array and loop over it
let total = [...prices].reduce((acc, price) => {
    return acc + parseFloat(price.innerHTML);  
}, 0);
```

This would however require you to edit the `HTML`

From

```
<div class='price'>$429.00 (GST Inc)</div>
```

To something like -

```
<div><span>$</span><div class='price'>429.00</div> <span>(GST Inc)</span></div>
```

or you could use a [regular expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) on the `price.innerHTML`

Comment: Or just use what I did. No need to change HTML at all

Comment: @mplungjan thats why i upvoted your answer, I was giving another way to go, also I replied 5 seconds after you :)

Comment: Actually 23 minutes later but who's counting ;)